# SnailSVN Lite: difftool crashes

Tags: svn

I installed snailsvn lite. When i first tried to double click a file in the commit dialog i had to install difftools manually.
I did copy the difftool.sh into `~/Library/Application\ Scripts/net.langui.SnailSVN.DiffTool`, but when i try it now, the window opens(empty) loads for a few seconds and closes again.
I tried restarting the macbook, adding the above path in the sanilsvn settings, but nothing helped.
Can anyone help me getting it working?